# Tridion DXA page not loading (loads eventually but take whole lot of time)

Tags: 2013-sp1, dxa, sdl-tridion

We have a DXA 1.7 application, the site works fine most of the time, but sometimes the page load takes almost 5 minutes and during that time I get the below exception in event viewer log.

"The process cannot access the file 'BinaryData\100011\Images\test-image.jpg' because it is being used by another process."

Please suggest what could be the issue here or direction to troubleshoot the issue.

Comment: seems like it's concurrency problems with Binary Module, you may have to fix BinaryModule to implement a file lock mutex mechanism, not sure it's fixed in DXA framework DXA 1.7, it's already Retired, think of upgrading to latest version.

Comment: You don’t have something else scanning the images do you (such as a virus checker), just something I’ve seen before.

Answer (score 0):

will it possible to browse following image: (hostname)\BinaryData\100011\Images\test-image.jpg?

in case normal scenario will this image be downloading?

if this image can be traced try to delete this image. before deleting make sure your application does not have any reference of this image.

sometimes 3rd party integration caused this kind of issues. it was worth checking those integrations too 1.e: search, analytics etc.